# What kind of resistor is this symbol?

Tags: power-electronics, schematics, eaglecad

I'm looking at some power circuitry and trying to determine whether this is just a normal resistor with some extra nodes either side, or some kind of shunt resistor symbol or something?
[image: Odd resistor symbol with extra legs]

Comment: It is a shunt with two connections for current and another two to measure the voltage across the the shunt.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a resistor with a Kelvin connection, specifically for measuring current (the fact that it's a \$0.01 \Omega\$ resistor is also a hint).

The idea is that your circuit board traces will significantly alter the resistance of the circuit, so you pick off the voltage right at the resistor for your measurement.

There are resistors out there that come with a built-in Kelvin connection, or if it's surface-mount you can hand-route your board to pick off the voltage right at the resistor pads, or you can use a standard resistor and design a "Kelvin" footprint for it, with each resistor end landing on a big current-carrying pad and a little voltage-sampling pad.

Each approach has its advantages and drawbacks; it's up to you to decide what's best.

Here's a picture of the top copper of a board I designed, focusing on a current sense resistor that has a Kelvin connection.  All of the thick traces are the current-carrying ones; the thin traces that come out of the center of the pads and go off to vias are the voltage pickoff.  Because the pickoffs are in areas of low current flow, they come close to sampling the "actual" voltage across the resistor, even though I chose 2-terminal resistors.

[image]